# Is there a .NET porting of Domain Driven Design's "Time and Money" project?

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design

Is there a .NET porting of Domain Driven Design's "[Time and Money](http://sourceforge.net/projects/timeandmoney/)" project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this was never ported to .Net, mainly I guess since the projects are by nature so domain specific it's rare for one to be ported at all.

There are however, a lot of other examples out there for .Net, check out this question's answers, hopefully something useful for you: [Samples for Domain Driven Design (esp .NET focused)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280681/samples-for-domain-driven-design-esp-net-focused)